# Can we insert javascript into any webpage loaded in the browser

Tags: javascript

I am looking into methods to inject javascript into any webpage loaded in the browser, so that I can traverse through the page's DOM. I use JQUERY for my scripting needs.
Method should work in all browsers.

I tried using **IFRAME** and adding some html into it, but I cant. Please suggest some ways.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a webpage and an Iframe inside of it, and when a page is loaded in the Iframe you want to traverse the DOM in it?

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using Greasemonkey: http://www.greasespot.net/. You can use it to execute custom scripts on page load for any website you want. You can find some basic tutorials here: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials.

Comment: I was looking for something to do this, so thanks. I tend to use Safari but found the [Greasekit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/) plugin that allows running of some Greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: Wish it was available for Chrome as well. the Requestly extension for chrome does not run offline, it takes you to their website to set up rules. I don't feel safe with that.

Comment: @Shayan - This is Sachin, Founder @ Requestly. We just use our webapp for configuring the rules because it just makes development & deployments easier. At Requestly, we take privacy very seriously. This is perfectly safe in every term and we store all your data in your browser. Feel free to reachout to discuss any concerns at contact@requestly.io

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to create a page with two iframes one to navigate to the designated website and other to get DOM Objects.
in the first one navigate to the site and then select its HTML and 
 append it in the body of the second Iframe.

```
iframe2.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = iframe1.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

then traverse the DOM Objects inside the second Iframe with your custom functions

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of approaches to solve this problem.

### Using BookMarklet

You can create a simple bookmarklet which injects jQuery on the page and you can open Dev Console in your favorite browser and try out your DOM inspection using jQuery or whatever you want to try out.

### Use Requestly Chrome Extension

You can use [Requestly Script Rule](https://medium.com/@requestly_ext/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a) to insert scripts on any webpage. Since your post mentions that you need jQuery, Requestly provides an option to include jQuery as well.

So with a simple click, you can write jQuery supported code without worrying about how jQuery will come in the page. Check these screenshots for reference :-

#### Script Rule Selection

[image]

#### Sample Script Supported by jQuery

[image]

### Advantages

A Couple of advantages with using [Requestly](https://www.requestly.in)

1. You can share the script with other Users using the [Requestly Share feature](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/14/share-rules-with-other-users/)
2. jQuery is by default supported
3. After creating the rule, you can simply disable it once you are not using it.
4. Requestly is available on Firefox as well as Chrome so you can run your script cross-browser.

PS: This may be an older post but answering here because the question is still relevant. 
Disclaimer: I am the founder of Requestly So you blame me if you don't like something.

Comment: This is very cool. I just started using Requestly, but I don't see how to run the page or gather the results.

Comment: @TrevordeKoekkoek Do you mind reaching out to us at contact@requestly.in with more details and I'd be glad to help you out. You can directly open https://app.requestly.in/rules to open the rules page and click on Add button to create a new rule.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bookmarklet (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) which in turn can add a  node to the page, with the src pointing to where your own javascript is located. Onde the script node gets added it will run.
You can find more details on http://www.johnvey.com/features/deliciousdirector/ under "how does it work?". This way you can have a bookmark in your bookmarks bar which, when click, will add your script to any page you happen to be on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for Chrome [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) to add custom scripts for a specific web page which is as well awesome and I can really recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute a javascript code in any websites you are using in any browser. That means you have to go browser by browser different applications. In chrome supports extension same as firefox, edge, safari browsers supports add-ons. You can add the relevant extension to do that. I am using a [scripting](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/website-scripting/aggnfbkmhedkekjoplldenefbchaoiln) extension, that can run the given script whenever I open the page with same URL given in the script. Likewise you have to find different applications for different browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You can't run Javascript on arbitrary Web pages that you do not control the content of. It would be a **huge** security hole if that were not true.

Think about it: you could run Javascript and wait for someone to log on to their internet banking and then do something with the characters input.

Comment: Just to clarify this point: Javascript you serve in a webpage cannot operate on another webpage from another domain (see XSS link in question comment). 

However, for your own local needs, you can run javascript on any page your browser has loaded, either via the browser's javascript console or other tools like Greasemonkey.

Comment: are you sure. Coz i have run script through chrome into amazon to get a product from a flash sale and successfully got it also.

Comment: @AndrewShooner pls see this https://blog.sriraman.in/script-to-buy-yureka-plus-buy-amazon-successfully/. My friend used this script to get this phone and i can confirm that he successfully got it. And it was Amazon in which he injected the sccript, which is not a small website.

Comment: Yes, this was the point I had attempted to clarify: you can run any javascript you wish locally on your browser's loaded DOM  (using the javascript console or other methods), but your browser's single-origin policy prohibits the execution javascript downloaded from a different domain than the page that loaded it, unless you use a method such as JSONP or CORS.

Comment: @AndrewShooner But that can lead to DOS attacks and thats why i disagree from the answer

Comment: of course you can run it. Just open a developer tools, for example, and run whatever script you want. Or create an extension to chrome, which can inject js... dude. youre wrong

Comment: The question asked other thing, you answered other.

Comment: @AndrewShooner This answer OP  always provides very ambiguous answers and yet they are voted.

Answer (score -5):

Take a look at [jquery JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [Wikipedia's JSON page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Alternatively you can simply add a `<script>` tag to the document:

```
$("head").append('<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

This will load the javascript file.