# Adding a local JS script to a website whenever i visit it?

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know if it's possible but basically I have this problem:

I have a website that I regularly visit and it has a tons of sub-urls.
I wrote myself another script / site which I'm using on XAMMP / localhost to analyze things (based on the website).

Now whenever I visit said website, I want there to be button (on each site) that links a href to my localhost. So whenever I have XAMMP running, I could simply click to create a new tab from the website to my localhost site.
This as opposed to having to manually open my corresponding localhost site.

Is something like this possible ?
If not, would there be another feasible solution to "sort of" alter the website so I can use it better in conjunction with my custom scripts ?

Comment: I'd do it using a browser extension. LMK if this is a valid direction according to your needs

Comment: @galAbra that would be absolutely be a valid direction ! Are you perhaps able to give me some more hinters (i havent messed with firefox or chrome extensions at all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we insert javascript into any webpage loaded in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551067/can-we-insert-javascript-into-any-webpage-loaded-in-the-browser)

Comment: You can use [Requestly](https://requestly.io) Script Rule - https://medium.com/requestly-docs/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a to insert your code in all web pages you visit. Infact, you can also load some inbuilt libraries like jQuery before loading your script.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to see chrome/Firefox extension Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey which allows running userscripts.